# Embedding of 3-manifold $S^3/Q_8$ in $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: manifolds

In paper of Hantzsche (1938) there is proof that boundary of tubular neighborhood of $RP^2$ in $R^4$ (denote it $M$) is $S^3/Q_8$. I was trying to read this work but I don't know German, so this is difficult.

I Hantzsche's paper there is following formula
$(\sin u \cos \frac{v}{2}, \sin u \sin \frac{v}{2}, \cos u \cos v, \cos u \sin v) $ on page 49. Is it parametrization of $\mathbb RP^2$ ? Earlier I read:
"Dreht man in einer Projektiven ebene eine Gerade (das ist ein topologischer Kreis) um einen ihrer Punkte durch en Winkel $\pi$, so uberstreicht sie dabei die projektive Ebene vollstandig. Wir benutzen diese Eigenschaft der projektiven Ebene um sie in den R4 einzulagern. " which Google translate to
"In a projective plane, if one turns a straight line (that is a topological circle) around one of its points through an angle $\pi$, then it completely passes over the projective plane. We use this property of the projective plane to store them in the $R^4$."

Another idea I have is to define $\mathbb RP^2$ in $\mathbb R^4$ as efect of gluing three rectangles. Next obtain triangulation (or cubification) of M
by thickening each rectangle to 4-cube. The boundary will be built out of twelve 3-cubes. I don't know though how to define gluings of these 3-cubes.

Comment: I *think* you can do this by double covering your normal bundle by a bundle over $S^2$, and then the boundary is an $S^1$ bundle over $S^2$, and so is a quotient of $S^3$. Which quotient is completely determined by the Euler number. All this assumes the tubular neighborhood you started with was nontrivial, but I'm guessing that's true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have gotten most of the way there. I still don't know two things (listed at the end). I did find a nice reference that talks about this though (in a more general setting): Lawson's *Normal Bundles for an embedded $\mathbb{RP}^2$ in a Positive Definite 4-manifold* ([PDF](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/lawson4.pdf)).

So let $N$ be your tubular neighborhood, and assume it is non-trivial (not just $\mathbb{RP}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$). According to Rochlin's *Two-dimensional Submanifolds of Four-dimensional Manifolds* ([PDF](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/rohlin2.pdf)), it has Euler number $\pm2$.  It is double-covered by a disk bundle over $S^2$, which has Euler number $\pm4$. The boundary is a nontrivial $S^1$ bundle over $S^2$, which is thus a quotient of $S^3$.  If we write this boundary as $M$, then ignoring orientation issues we have a 4-sheeted covering $S^3\rightarrow M$, and since $M$ double-covers $\partial N$, we have an 8-sheeted covering $S^3\rightarrow \partial N$.

We can thus write $\partial N$ as $S^3/G$, where $G$ is a group of order $8$ acting on $S^3$.  We get this group because the covering $S^3\rightarrow M$ comes from a quotient of an action by a subgroup of $S^3$ [thought of as unit quaternions], and then we extend that by the $C_2$ action going from $M$ to $\partial N$.

The two questions I have not yet answered are:

1. Why is the normal bundle nontrivial?
2. Why is $G$ the quaternion group and not $C_8$?

**Edit**: The question has changed substantially since I added this answer.  The OP is looking at a specific embedding, and asking about explicit generators in $\pi_1(\partial T)$, the fundamental group of the boundary of the tubular neighborhood.  Perhaps that can be extracted from this answer (with effort).  Anyway, I'll complete this answer, which shows for **any** embedding $\mathbb{RP}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$, the boundary of a tubular neighborhood is homeomorphic to $S^3/Q_8$.

Answer to (1): @JasonDeVito gave a nice explanation in the comments below.  It also follows from Rochlin's paper cited above, although it is not easy to tease it out!

Answer to (2): We already have that $M$ [the boundary of the disk bundle over $S^2$] is $S^3/\langle i\rangle$, treating $\langle i\rangle$ as a subgroup of $S^3$, the unit quaternions. Now if we think about $S^3$ as pairs of complex numbers and $S^2$ as $\mathbb{CP}^1$, then the Hopf fibration is $(z,w)\mapsto [z:w]$. In this setting, the $C_2$ action corresponding to the covering $S^2\rightarrow\mathbb{RP}^2$ sends $[z:w]$ to $[-\overline{w}:\overline{z}]$. Up in $S^3$, this is simply multiplication by $j$. [*I should be more careful here since we're dealing with a nonabelian group: the action is on the left for both $i$ and $j$ multiplying $S^3$*]. Thus we have a factorization of the covering
$$ S^3\rightarrow S^3/\langle i,j\rangle\rightarrow \partial T$$

Since $S^3$ is an 8-sheeted covering of both those spaces, the second arrow is a 1-sheeted covering; that is, a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. Quoted papers are interesting in 4-manifolds area. I am looking for more elementary proof - how generators of $\pi_1$ can be defined and why they are order 4. These circles should be order 2 in homology $H_1=\mathbb Z_2+\mathbb Z_2$. I will add more details tomorrow to my question. Regards,

Comment: For 1.  The normal bundle of any embedding $f:\mathbb{R}P^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is non-trivial if $n$ is not of the form $2^k - 1$, (e.g. $n=2$).  For, if $n$ doesn't have this form, then according to Milnor-Stasheff's Characteristic classes, Corollary 4.6, there is at least one non-zero Stiefel-Whitney class of $\mathbb{R}P^n$, say $w_i(T\mathbb{R}P^n) \neq 0$.  However, if the normal bundle $\nu$ to $\mathbb{R}P^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is trivial, then $0 = f^*(w_i(T\mathbb{R}^m)) = w_i(f^* T\mathbb{R}^m) = w_i(T\mathbb{R}P^n\oplus \nu) = w_i(T\mathbb{R}P^n)$, giving a contradiction.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: thanks! I also see how to do 2, so I'll edit so that the answer is complete.

Comment: Very nice!  One question: What is an Euler number?  If it's just another name for Euler class - don't you need to know that the bundle is orientable to compute it?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: it's the torsion Euler number (see Rochlin's paper). I guess you can also just work with the double-cover (the disk bundle over the sphere).

Comment: @JasonDeVito: sorry for my short response earlier, I had to run out.  In fact I was wrong, the definiiton is not in Rochlin's paper, I had my references mixed up.  When I was searching for an answer to my question (1), I came across [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8516), where the first few paragraphs of section 2 seem to summarize the Euler number quite nicely.  All these sources point back to [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102978058) by Massey, which gives exactly the result I needed from Rochlin's paper....

Comment: ...His paper contains an appendix that goes over the Euler number for non-orientable surfaces.  Basically, $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2)$ acts non-trivially on $\mathbb{Z}$, and with this structure one has $H^2(\mathbb{RP}^2,\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$. You define the Euler class then as you normally would: orient each fiber, show (with these twisted coefficents) you can glue them in a compatible way, then take the pullback via the zero section. But I am very out of my comfort zone here, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: @SteveD Thank you for your effort ! I do not follow how do we "have that $M$ is $S^3/<i>$ ? Also I do not see how $C_2$ action sends $[z:w]$ to $[-w:z]$ ? Can you give more details on these arguments ?

Comment: @SteveD:  Thanks!  I had looked at Rochlin's paper before asking you the question, but I was quite tired then, so I figured I just missed it.  Thanks for the extra references!

Comment: @MarekMitros: An oriented circle bundle over $S^2$ is $S^3/\langle\exp(2\pi i/q)\rangle$, where $q$ is the Euler number.  In our case, $q=\pm4$. You are right about the $C_2$ action though! That should be $[z:w]\rightarrow [-\overline{w}:\overline{z}]$.  This is just the antipodal map, but in $\mathbb{CP}^1$ coordinates.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks. One argument why $\partial N$ must by non trivial bundle is because it is orientable manifold. $RP^2\times S^1$ is not.